# Weird "undefined tab position" error when using Doxygen generated LaTeX code (minimal snippet provided)

Tags: tabbing, doxygen

I have a strange "undefined tab position" error when using Doxygen to generate LaTeX and PDF. I was able to narrow down which block produces this error. I cannot post the entire LaTeX code, but I am able to try experiments to narrow the error. Here's the problematic code (and the first occurrence of the `tabbing` environment):

```
\begin{DoxyCompactItemize}
\item \mbox{\Hypertarget{union__something__t_a042e33d2990a01b2561e0d44f98f2316}\label{union__something__t_a042e33d2990a01b2561e0d44f98f2316}} 
\begin{tabbing}
xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=xx\=\kill
struct \{\\
\}; \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
```

The error is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.18 \begin{tabbing}
                    
?
```

The error goes away when I simply put a `\hrulefill` before the `DoxyCompactItemize` tag - i.e., the following works correctly with no error.

```
\hrulefill % <-- this fixes the problem!
\begin{DoxyCompactItemize}
% ... same stuff as before ... %
\end{DoxyCompactItemize}
```

There are several such `DoxyCompactItemize` things in the rest of the code that also seem to compile without issues. So, it seems like \hrulefill is resetting something allowing rest of the tabbing environments to work correctly.

Here's the definition of `DoxyCompactItemize` from the `doxygen.sty` file:

```
% Used for member lists
\newenvironment{DoxyCompactItemize}{%
  \begin{itemize}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-3pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
}{%
  \end{itemize}%
}
```

I've used LaTeX while I was in school but I am not an expert on it. I'd appreciate any debug suggestions based on what I posted above and the experiments I've tried. I am also open to trying out other experiments.

I am curious to know why adding a `\hrulefill` hides the problem under the rug? I reviewed the output and it looks good as well (with the exception of the unnecessary horizontal line).

Appreciate your help and suggestions. Thank You.

Comment: you should show what is before the hrulefill.

Comment: You have only shown snippets. Nothing that we could compile (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows your problem. As it is I (we) have no idea what you might or might not have done. --- GOM

Comment: Unfortunately, the document I am trying to compile is a large one that I cannot post as it is. I'll try to see what I can do to remove large sections, but yet keeping the compilation error as it is. In the snippet I posted above, I am puzzled as to why LaTeX is complaining about a missing tab position even though the tabbing environment is correctly defined. Are there other things outside the tabbing environment that can potentially cause a "undefined tab position" error? Appreciate the comments so far.

Comment: To update, I've been trying to remove large chunks of code in an attempt to reproduce a minimal sample, but I am noticing that removing random chunks of code makes the issue go away. In fact, simply removing the `\mbox{Hypertarget...` line also makes the issue go away. So, I am wondering if I need to approach it from the first principles. Is there a way to get more information about the error that will direct me in the right direction? (why does LaTeX think I am missing a tab position even though I am not?).

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Looks like you have an anonymous struct inside a union `Something_T`, maybe you can reduce the code to only this part and run doxygen and pdflatex on it? Is the code public domain or propriety?

Comment: How and where is `\Hypertarget` defined? The `hyperref` package defines `\hypertarget` with lower case, but that is a different command (because command names are case sensitive) and it has two arguments while the command in your code has only one.

Comment: Hypertarget seems to be defined in doxygen.sty as `\newcommand{\Hypertarget}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}`.

Comment: Also, I think I *may* have found the problem. Doxygen redefines `\+` as `\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{\scriptsize$\hookleftarrow$}}{}{}}` and uses `\+` liberally when it autogenerates LaTeX code. What I found was whenever this hyphenation hint occurs in the document's footer (say `\fancyfoot[L]{...\+...}`), then LaTeX complains of missing tab position. If I remove all the `\+`s in the footer (only), then the problem goes away. I still don't fully know how these are related, but I do know that '\+' has special meaning in a tabbing environment. For now, I am considering this good enough.

Comment: Also, after adding the hyphenation hints, doxygen puts the identifier in a `\mbox` which makes the hyphenation pointless (correct me if I am wrong) - i.e., I see things like `\mbox{\hyperlink{...}{A\+_VERY\+_LONG\+_IDENTIFIER}}` which never gets broken across line boundaries.